# Couldn't fetch all woocommerce products in pyqtSlot

Tags: python, pyqt, python-multithreading, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to retrieve all woo-commerce products (2656 products) with pyqtSlot (pyqt thread). Unfortunately the thread is terminated without any exception after some iterations (sometimes after 4, sometime after 5).

I would be pleased if some can help me
Thanks in advance

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def fetch_product_images(self):
    per_page = 100
    page = 1

    products = sabapart.wcapi.get("products", params={'per_page': per_page, 'page': page}).json()

    try:
        while len(products) != 0:
            page += 1
            products = sabapart.wcapi.get("products", params={'per_page': per_page, 'page': page}).json()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception: {e}")
```

I tried changing per_page parameter, but it didn't change anything. Actually it doesn't matter the size of per_page.

Comment: Sorry but your question and its code are completely insufficient to understand the problem. Please improve your question by providing more detailed context and a proper [mre].